# How to write dictionary keys and corresponding values to each line to a file

Tags: python, dictionary

```
State_Dict = {"Texas": ["San Antonio, Austin, Houston"] ,
    "California": ["San Diego, Los Angeles, San Francisco"],
    "Florida": ["Miami", "Orlando", "Jacksonville"]}

with open("state.txt", "w") as state:
    for key, value in State_Dict:
        state.write(key, value)
```

Goal: I need to write the keys and values to a text file in the following format:

```
Texas
San Antonio
Austin
Houston
California
San Diego
Los Angeles
San Francisco
Florida
Miami
Orlando
Jacksonville
```

So far I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "snip/testBed_2.py", line 7, in <module>
    for key, value in State_Dict:
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

How do I make this work?

Comment: First of all you need the `items()` of the dictionary to iterate over. Then you need a second, inner, loop to iterate over the elements of the value list (or simply `str.join`). And `write()` isn't the best option here, try `print()` with `file` parameter instead.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a second loop to loop over your values as following. Since your values are a single list with a single element, you get the names of the cities using `[0]` index and then split them using `,` (comma) as the delimiter.

Some of your lists have all cities as a single string whereas some lists have individual city names. Hence you can use an if statement to check that. `v.strip()` removes the empty spaces from the names.

```
with open("state.txt", "w") as state:
    for key, value in State_Dict.items():
        state.write(key + '\n')
        if len(value) == 1:
            for v in value[0].split(','):
                state.write(v.strip() + '\n')
        else:
            for v in value:
                state.write(v.strip() + '\n')
```

**Output**

```
Texas
San Antonio
Austin
Houston
California
San Diego
Los Angeles
San Francisco
Florida
Miami
Orlando
Jacksonville
```

Comment: Thank you for noticing the differences in the city names! This was going to be my follow up question. :)  Thank you so much!